# Rstudio doesn't start, displaying the logo only, neither r console doesn't work

Tags: r, rstudio, macos-sonoma

- After I updated my M1-based MacBook to MacOS Sonoma 14.0, RStudio and the R console don't work.
- When I try to open RStudio, it only displays its logo. So, I tried R console, but while initializing the program, it always freezes.
- When I implement R console in the terminal with the following code:

  /Applications/R.app/Contents/MacOS/R

an error pops up saying, 2023-10-17 17:49:45.520 R[29414:94968]

> WARNING: Secure coding is not enabled for restorable state! Enable
> secure coding by implementing

```
NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState: and returning YES.
```

- I also tried to search the way I can access to `NSApplicationDelegate` or editing the value of `applicationSupportSecureRestorableState`, but sadly I couldn't.
- Although I deleted & reinstalled the latest version of R & `Rstudio`, the same problem persists.
  (`R-4.3.1.arm64, RStudio-2023.09.0-463`)
- This prevents me from using this software, which is greatly impacting my project schedule.

Please share your wisdom. Thanks.

Comment: Hello! Please see [this thread](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-start-up-trouble-after-newest-mac-os-update-sonoma/175232/3) for similar issue recently. The last user suggest changing the "private relay" setting for Icloud. See what this does for you.